# UTF-8 with R Markdown, knitr and Windows

Tags: r, windows, utf-8, knitr, r-markdown

*What?*

An `.Rmd` file is error-free rendered via `knitr` (or `rmarkdown`) within from Linux. Related material (i.e. child R scripts and CSV input data) is all set in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Executing the same script from within Windows (actually the script is inside a cloned git repository), does not render all characters cleanly, since it's set to [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

*Examples*

For example, the string `"sans réserves"`, sourced from a CSV into some data.frame's column content, is typeset as `"sans rÃ©serves"`. To read this one correctly, it suffices to add `encoding='UTF-8'` to `read.csv`, obviously while reading-in the data.

Another example, that concerns an entry among other `R` code lines, is the string `"Trésorier Général"`. It is typeset as `"TrÃ©sorier GÃ©nÃ©ral"`. Fortunately, the following advice

```
read_chunk(lines = readLines("TestSpanishText.R", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15714617/1172302, works and the string is rendered as expected.

*Related*

[**Update**] There are some related Q&As, but they are more than 2-3 years old. As well, this page https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding, points to the very issue.

*Questions*

Is there another, easier way to overcome this issue regarding `UTF-8` and Windows, inside `R`? Recommendations on how to approach such a problem? I am trying to follow a *one source for all* principle.

> ps- An interesting reading: https://superuser.com/a/221602/128768

Comment: *"Is there another, easier way to overcome this issue"* - What **is** *"this issue"*? It seems you found out already, that for text to render properly, the renderer needs to know about its character encoding. Truth be told, [there ain't no such thing as Plain Text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @IInspectable Right, the renderer needs to know. The issue is altogether why bother to set anything for reading files and `read_chunk`ing the scripts? Why not say, in one place, all this is UTF-8, please render it correctly.

Comment: I don't know, if this is possible with R, but you could try to set the [code page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx) to 65001 on Windows, to indicate UTF-8.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you. Here the _issue_: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding

Comment: If I understand, you can set the default encoding in the IDE. Did I miss something, or are you looking for a solution that doesn't require the user to change their environment?

Comment: Each attempt to use `Sys.setlocale` returns `OS reports request to set locale to "UTF-8" cannot be honored` (in Windows 7), same as reported in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20571147/1172302. Reportedly, my colleague didn't get it working by setting this in `.Rprofile` too.

Comment: I have the same bug with R Knitr R and LaTeX... have you got a solution ?

Comment: @Hedjour No. I was trying to help a colleague at the time. I would still be interested to know how to solve this, though it doesn't bother me directly anymore. And, I don't run Windows to test.

Comment: Mojibake (`Ã©` for `é`) usually implies that latin1/cp1252 is incorrectly involved in the processing.  Is a database involved?